# Pandas - map values from one dataframe to another

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
 df_selected = pd.DataFrame({'player':['Keno', 'Filipe Luís', 'Thiago Galhardo'],
                             'selected': [2868.755, 776.147, 2696.853],
                             'ranking':[1,3,2]})
```

which prints:

```
            player        selected  ranking
0             Keno        2868.755        1
1      Filipe Luís         776.147        3
2  Thiago Galhardo        2696.853        2
```

and this one:

```
df_player = pd.DataFrame({'name':['Keno', 'Filipe Luís', 'Thiago Galhardo', 'SomePlayer'],
                    'team': ['Atlético-MG', 'Flamengo', 'Internacional', 'SomeTeam']})
```

which prints:

```
            player           team
0             Keno    Atlético-MG
1      Filipe Luís       Flamengo
2  Thiago Galhardo  Internacional
3           Fulano   TimeQualquer
```

Now I would like to check if a given player from `df_player` is in `df_selected` and, if so, fetch its ranking position and add it to a new column in `df_player`. If the player is not in `df_selected`, then add 0 value to its ranking. I've tried:

```
for ind, player in df_player.iterrows():
    for index, selected in df_selected.iterrows():

        if player.player == selected.player:
            df_player['ranking'].iloc[ind] = selected.ranking
        else:
            df_player['ranking'].iloc[ind] = 0
```

---

But it is not working, and there *must* be a simpler way of mapping those items.

Desired result for `player_df`:

```
            player         team    ranking
0             Keno    Atlético-MG        1
1      Filipe Luís       Flamengo        3
2  Thiago Galhardo  Internacional        2
3       SomePlayer       SomeTeam        0
```

---

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create dictionary of `player; ranking` from `df_selected` using `dict(zip())` and `map` to `df_player['name']`

```
df_player['ranking']=df_player['name'].map(dict(zip(df_selected.player,df_selected.ranking))).fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df_player)
 

          name           team  ranking
0             Keno    Atlético-MG        1
1      Filipe Luís       Flamengo        3
2  Thiago Galhardo  Internacional        2
3       SomePlayer       SomeTeam        0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it.

```
merge_dict = dict(zip(df_selected['player'], df_selected['ranking']))
df_player['ranking'] = df_player['player'].map(merge_dict)
```

I think that solves your problem, and will be much faster than your for loop.